# Animating a "d" value with Snap.svg erroring in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, safari, snap.svg

You can see the problem by opening http://cjohn.design in Chrome and Safari. The logo animation is suppose to animate one section at a time like it does in Safari - Chrome animation staled.

Here is the Snap.svg function that runs this:

```
function logo_in() {
    logo.animate ({
        d: p1
    }, 75, mina.easein);
            setTimeout(function() {
                logo.animate ({
                    d: p2
                }, 75, mina.easein);    
            }, 100);
            setTimeout(function() {
                logo.animate ({
                    d: p3
                }, 75, mina.easein);    
            }, 200);
            setTimeout(function() {
                logo.animate ({
                    d: p4
                }, 75, mina.easein);    
            }, 300);
            setTimeout(function() {
                logo.animate ({
                    d: p5
                }, 50, mina.easein);    
            }, 400);
};
```

The variables p0-p5 are the 6 stages of the logo animation. It is set to p0 by default and goes thru animating each with setTimeouts.

This worked up until recently. How would the logo start to animate so awkwardly?

Comment: I think you need to break out the relevant code only onto a jsfiddle or similar.

Comment: Update: I can't replicate the problem - it works fine on CodePen: http://codepen.io/cjohndesign/pen/PNVZwQ

Answer (score 1):

My CSS value

```
transition: all .8s ease
```

was clashing with the animation time value

```
logo.animate ({
    d: p1
}, **75**, mina.easein);
```